# Is it normal that WPF is a factor 100 or someting slower then the normal Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I've tried to create a very simple program which loads a string of about 100.000 characters of Html code in a TextBlock.

The text block itself is in a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,75,0,0">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>

</ScrollViewer>
```

I did the same in the windows forms TextBox control.

When I try to scroll in the document it lags behind about 0.25 seconds I think while running the cpu at 50% (dual core, so one core to 100%) and uses more and more memory (More then 170 mb).

When I scroll around in the text in the Windows Form Application it stays steady at 15 mb while maintaining a processor usage of below 15%.

Is this normal, or can anything be done to improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a readonly TextBox instead, it will perform much better in this scenario than a TextBlock.

Comment: Why does a TextBox perform better here?

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure of the exact reason TextBox performs better, my answer is derived from testing. I assume that TextBox is quicker as it is less sophisticated in terms of what it can render, just plain text. A TextBlock can render blocks\runs of text in different colors, fonts, sizes and with text decorations for example.